# re-rendering EJS file after an ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, highcharts, ejs

I am trying to make an Ajax call to my server upon a href click. When my href is clicked I successfully go to my server and call a defined route. My route serves me correctly and sends me back the data. Here below is the script which does that.

```
$('.graph-switch').click(function (){

event.preventDefault();

   $.getScript("js/ejs_production.js", function()
       $.ajax({
           url:'/spiderSwitch',
           type: 'GET',
           data: { type: $(this).attr('href') },
           success: function(result){
                console.log(result); // correctly displayed
                // WHAT TO DO AT THIS POINT??
           },
           error: function(){
              alert("well this is not working");
           }
       });
   });
});
```

At this point I need to re-render the part which I want to change. Here below is the part of HTML that I want to change.

```
<div class="panel-body text-center"><% include partials/spider-chart.ejs %> </div>
```

Basically I add a spider-chart.ejs file using the ejs's include keyword. Below is the spider-chart.ejs file.

```
<!-- views/partials/spider-chart.ejs -->

<!--NOTE: host pages must include the following in <head>-->
<!--<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js'></script>-->
<!--<script src="scripts/SpiderChartControl.js"></script>-->

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="chart" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 1000px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>

    var spiderGraphData = <%- JSON.stringify(spiderGraphData) %>
    var options = {
        metric: 'accuracy'
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(spiderGraphData));
    SpiderChartControl.draw("chart", spiderGraphData, options);
</script>
```

Basically it is a script which populates a div using high-charts library. As far as I understood there are two approaches which both I failed to make work.

something like this:

```
$("#id").innerHtml = "<div class='panel-body text-center'> <% include partials/spider-graph.ejs %> </div>";
```

or something like this using ejs constructs:

```
new EJS({url : 'partials/spider-chart.ejs' }).update('.tab-pane active', result);
```

I don't have high hopes for this question but there is no answer to this particular problem in any any web resource.

Comment: In which part are you having troubles? I see you have a small error, which is the event.preventDefault(), event is not defined you should define it in the function handler like fuction(event) { event.preventDefault() ....

Comment: I was having problems in the lack of documentation of doing this with new EJS construct. That is why finally I made it work with by changing the inner html.

Comment: Hey, I have a similar kind of problem. I used ajax to send users email and password to the server if they are correct then I need to take the user to another page? how is that possible. can I do that using ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well, the `/spiderSwitch` resource contains JSON data that you would like to use to populate the EJS template, and inject the generated HTML in the element that has the following class names: `panel-body text-center`.

According to the [EJS documentation](https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/Templates), you need to use the `.update()` method, as you stated in your question. However, the documentation is unclear on what does the first argument represent.

By browsing the [EJS code](https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/source/browse/trunk/src/ejs.js#99), I found that it actually should refer to an element's ID. Though, you don't have any element with the `.tab-pane active` ID in your code.

If you want to select the element by its classname, you need to use `document.querySelector` as such:

```
new EJS({
    url: 'partials/spider-chart.ejs'
}).update(
    document.querySelector('.panel-body.text-center'),
    result
);
```

By the way, as @balder said, you have a reference error in your code, if you want to use the `event` argument, you must declare it in the function arguments:

```
function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.getScript(/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: this answer seems to be the correct way to do it with new EJS() construct. Although it is still possible to change the inner html of the page which I ended up doing with.